# How to check whether java installed or not through shell script

Tags: shell

I need to check whether java installed or not through shell script on Linux.

If not , how can i install the JRE through this script file.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: http://www.gimlisys.com/articles-detect-java.html Try this link...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

type java || yum install jre

will look for java binary on the path and will try to install jre if java is not present

Comment: yum install jre looks downlods jre from the internet, instead it should install the one that is bundled with the package.

Comment: Of course, jre can be installed via a tarball, instead of using rpms and yum repos. Replace yum install jre by your preferred jre deploy method

Answer (score 2):

**Solution 1:**

In your terminal type `java -version` or just `javac` if it returns something, then you've java installed. Otherwise, there is also the possibility that the path variables do not contain the java path. So use locate jdk or locate java to see if you have the java binary.

**Solution 2:**

As mentioned above, You should be able to run `which java` or `java -version`

**Sample Output:**

[image]